# Ruby and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I started writing a simple Sinatra app today and I am trying to understand the error reporting but for some reason I can't get it to work correctly.

I know here, http://railsapi.com/doc/sinatra-v1.0/, it talks about working with error reporting/handling but when I run their examples I can't get it to work.

```
require 'sinatra'

error 400..510 do
  'Boom'
end

get '/say/*' do
  params[:splat]
end
```

When I run the app on my computer I get a 404 error code, but the `'Boom'` text does not display in the browser, just the browser 404 page. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will wager its your browser.  On my MacBook Pro:

Chrome "helpfully" displays a "Oops!  This link appears to be broken." page.

Safari displays the expected `Boom` text.

Firefox displays the expected `Boom` text.

Comment: Thanks! Thats odd that Chrome would do this... oh well, back to using FF for Sinatra testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sinatra throws Sinatra::NotFound exception (404) to a specific handler. Simply modify the code as follows,

```
require 'sinatra'

not_found do
  'Boom in NOT_FOUND.'
end

error 400..510 do
  'Boom'
end

get '/say/*' do
  params[:splat]
end
```

It works well in Chrome and Firefox on Mac OSX.